# How I can control the first character in a string if this is a return "\r"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, datatable, return

hi I have a List and i use a foreach to control every line in this List.

If the first character in the line is a return ="\r" then I don't want add the line to ArrayList.

here my code:

```
foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    if (line != string.Empty)
                    {
                        string first_charakter = line.Substring(0, 1);

                        if (first_charakter != "-" || first_charakter != " " || first_charakter != "\r")
                        {
                            list_of_programs.Add(line);
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Does your code work? If not what is the problem? Or are you asking for a code review?

Comment: There's no need to use a `ArrayList` anymore. Use a generic `List<String>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to include them so don't use `&&`, you can use a collection as lookup + `Contains`:

```
char[] iDontWant = { ' ', '-', '\r' };
if(!iDontWant.Contains(first_charakter))
{
    list_of_programs.Add(line);
}
```

or even one line for all with LINQ:

```
list_of_programs = lines
   .Where(l => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(l) && !iDontWant.Contains(l[0]))
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

fix and little refactoring

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
     {
          if (line[0] != "-" && line[0] != " " && line[0] != "\r")
          {
               list_of_programs.Add(line);
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Typo:  `IsNotNullOrEmpty`?

Comment: yes, it is typo, fixed